"Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 32"
I learn more about node.js and fastify when 'send request' the request return this message : "Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 32"
how i know where is the problem?
the code :
import { fastify } from "fastify"
import { DatabaseMemory } from "./database-memory.js"

const server = fastify()

const database = new DatabaseMemory()

server.post("/videos", (request, reply) => {
  const body = request.body

  console.log(body)

  database.create({
    title: "Video 01",
    description: "teste",
    duration: 180,
  })

  return reply.status(201).send()
})

server.get("/videos", () => {
  return "video 01"
})

server.put("/videos/:id", () => {
  return "esse video"
})

server.delete("/videos/:id", () => {
  return "esse video"
})

server.listen({
  port: 1313,
})

i tried put the double-quoted but dont's work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems that the DatabaseMemory does not work to me
